# c# mysql zipcode radius on a map

Tags: c#, mysql

hope I ask this one the right way.  What i'm basically trying to do is cover the US in 75 mile radius circles (based on zipcode) with as little overlap as possible.  I've been able to do zipcodes 75 miles apart but the problem is those overlap at 50%.  So I think if i include the distance to be 150 miles apart, this would cause as little overlap as possible.  Then i run into the issue of how do I know which area's of the US aren't covered?  So I would like to draw these radius circles on a map.  Does anybody have a good starting point?

Edit:  I also have the lat/lng with these zipcodes.  So essentially i'm saying 75 mile radius from zip code X.

Comment: are you trying to do something like this - see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983325/calculate-distance-between-zip-codes-and-users/3989830#3989830

Comment: Sorta, i'm more or less trying to draw radius maps on a US map using as few overlaps as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Zipcodes aren't of anything like a common area.  Your 75 mile circle here will completely contain *MANY* zip codes.  I think you need to rethink your approach.