# How to calculate the distance between two locations with ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, geocoding, distance

I'm wondering about the feasability of this below. Of course, I'm not asking for the complete code (although it would be nice!) but rather a way to achieve the following in ASP.NET:

I have a site. People register on it and provide their Country of residence as well as the ZIP code and City name which is then stored in a SQL Server DB. I have a search engine on my site and I would like one of the filtering options to be "only show me members living at a maximum distance of 100 kilometers".

Any ideas, hints, already written code I can re-use, free API's doing just that, etc... ?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: -1 Question shows very little effort.  Just a quick search of SO came up with at least a dozen very near duplicates.  Edit: Perhaps I'm just a cranky old man inside, but in my opinion, people should not have to read those (after all, you said yourself "actually, my first Google search...")

Comment: Thank you for the -1. I actually searched SO and I could find many post related to the calculation between two locations but didn't see one that would point me in the direction on how to check the distance between one location and over 20k of them in an efficient way without testing all the available location. If you check the below discussion with Mr Straton, you'd understand. But yeah, as said, thank you.

Comment: Based on your title and the possibility of using an API, I assumed you were focusing on the actual calculation, not how to do it on a large set efficiently.  That being the case, a lot of my original comment is nullified, and perhaps your post does not deserve a -1.  On a different note, you may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983325/calculate-distance-between-zip-codes-and-users helpful.

Comment: That is actually useful. English not being my native language, I didn't find it at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a way to look up the geocode (latitude and longitude) from the zip code. There are several web services for this, and also CSV files that you can download containing this data.  Google, for example, provides geolocaiton servivces.  I believe their API will also tell you the distance between two points.

At any rate, once you know the geocode, it's a simple matter of determining the distance using math.  Sample code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12269/Distance-between-locations-using-latitude-and-long):

(actually, my first Google search came up with a [complete solution](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/how-do-i-determine-the-distance-between-zip-codes-using-c/634).)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. This works with the US when having access to a file containing an exhaustive list of zip codes and their geolocation info. How would I approach this for a worldwide audience?

Comment: Google has geocodes for the worldwide audience, and a google search should turn up more services for doing this if you don't want to use Google.

Comment: Yup, I was just finding this. On the other hand, I found loads of examples to calculate the distance between two zip codes and I think I understand the formula (at least, the way to use it). Now, how would I go about finding all the locations close to a given one? Would a "for ... next" loop checking the distance on each zip work on about 50k registered members located in about 20k locations?

Comment: We do is using SQL Server and user-defined functions.  We have all our locations in a database with lat/long and use these functions when selecting a store near a given geocode: http://blog.troyd.net/SQL+Server+20002005+Function+To+Calculate+Distance+In+Miles+Between+2+Latitudelongitude+Points+For+Zip+Radius+Search+Etc.aspx