# Find users within the radius of location based on zip code

Tags: sql, database, geolocation, gis, zipcode

I have an app/site and need to perform a search for all users located within a user specified distance of their zip code. I have two tables, one with user data and a second with zip code information. I'm having difficulties figure out the query to find users that are within the distance.  I don't understand geospatial query needed to make it work.

**User Table Structure**

```
username        zip 
=====================   
tester55        60608   
Tester1         00544   
iosuser1        73120   
Tester3         01002
```

**Zipcodes Table Structure**

```
zip     latitude     longitude
------------------------------
00501   40.8154      -73.0451
00544   40.8154      -73.0451
01001   42.0702      -72.6227
01002   42.3671      -72.4646
```

I want to use the zip code of a user to find other users within a certain radius.  Here are the queries I have so far, I'm trying to figure out how to make it one query.

First Query

```
    Select users.zip, users.username, zipcodes.zip as user zip, 
zipcodes.longitude as userlong, zipcodes.latitude as userlat
from users, zipcodes where users.zip = zipcodes.zip AND username = 'tester55
```

Second Query

```
SELECT zipcodes.zip, zipcodes.city, zipcodes.state, zipcodes.longitude, zipcodes.latitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(userlat) ) * cos( radians( zipcodes.latitude ) ) 
    * cos( radians( zipcodes.longitude ) - radians(userlong) ) + sin( radians(userlat) ) * sin(radians(zipcodes.latitude)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM zipcodes
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doing it this way is bound to be super messy. Using a database with good GIS support is better, or at the absolute least, use [MySQL Spatial Extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html).

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  @Shadow can you remove the duplicate label so I can get responses.

Comment: I obviously think it is a duplicate, otherwise I would not have chosen to close it down as such. If you do not think it is a duplicate, then pls elaborate why not. Your question is about joining the same tables multiple times in a single query. This is exactly what is described in the duplicate topic.

Comment: I've edited the question to show that the focus is on not on joining but the syntax required to find users within a radius.  That's the part I'm in need of help with and have been searching for days.  If any question is a duplicate it is [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983325/calculate-distance-between-zip-codes-and-users?rq=1 . I've reviewed that question and still didn't get the answer needed.