# SQL Query to find 5 mile radius of a given zip code

Tags: sql

I'm currently using Redshift and I have a table that has a list of zip codes along with their latitudes and longitudes. I'm trying to write a sql statement where I can specify a given zip code and have it return all of the zip codes within a 5 mile radius.

Any ideas on how I can approach this?

Here's what I had tried:

```
SELECT zip, city, latitude, longitude,
  69.0* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
             * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
             * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
             + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
             * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_miles
```

FROM zip_code_db
 JOIN (
     SELECT  42.81  AS latpoint,  -70.81 AS longpoint
   ) AS p ON 1=1
 ORDER BY distance_in_miles

I'm trying to see if there is a way to use zip codes instead of specifying latitues and longitudes

Comment: can you post your table structure and what have you tried so far?

Comment: There are already thousands of post available to the problem related to this https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between Zip Codes... AND users.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983325/calculate-distance-between-zip-codes-and-users)

Comment: Yes, I had given this link a try and was wondering if there was a way to use zip codes instead of the latitutdes and longitudes:

Comment: A zip code is an _area_, not a _point_. If you want to keep it simple your best bet is to assign a lat/long to a zip code (in the middle somewhere) and approximate it that way. Otherwise you need to do things like work out the longest distance between the outside borders of two areas