# SQL to batch re-tag items

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got a MySQL database with typical schema for tagging items:

```
item (1->N) item_tag (N->1) tag
```

Each tag has a name and a count of how many items have that tag
ie:

```
item 
(
 item_id (UNIQUE KEY) 
)

item_tag 
(
 item_id (NON-UNIQUE INDEXED), 
 tag_id (NON-UNIQUE INDEXED)
)

tag
(
 tag_id (UNIQUE KEY)
 name
 count
)
```

I need to write a maintenance routine to batch re-tag one or more existing tags to a single new or existing other tag.  I need to make sure that after the retag, no items have duplicate tags and I need to update the counts on each tag record to reflect the number of actual items using that tag.

Looking for suggestions on how to implement this efficiently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've got so far, which seems to work but I don't have enough data yet to know how well it performs.  Comments welcome.

Some notes:

- Had to add a unique id field to to the item_tags table get the duplicate tag cleanup  working.
- Added support for tag aliases so that there's a record of retagged tags.
- I didn't mention this before but each item also has a published flag and only published items should affect the count field on tags.
- The code uses C#, subsonic+linq + "coding horror", but is fairly self explanatory.

The code:

```
public static void Retag(string new_tag, List<string> old_tags)
{
    // Check new tag name is valid
    if (!Utils.IsValidTag(new_tag))
    {
        throw new RuleException("NewTag", string.Format("Invalid tag name - {0}", new_tag));
    }

    // Start a transaction
    using (var scope = new SimpleTransactionScope(megDB.GetInstance().Provider))
    {
        // Get the new tag
        var newTag = tag.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name == new_tag);

        // If the new tag is an alias, remap to the alias instead
        if (newTag != null && newTag.alias != null)
        {
            newTag = tag.SingleOrDefault(x => x.tag_id == newTag.alias.Value);
        }

        // Get the old tags
        var oldTags = new List<tag>();
        foreach (var old_tag in old_tags)
        {
            // Ignore same tag
            if (string.Compare(old_tag, new_tag, true)==0)
                continue;
            var oldTag = tag.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name == old_tag);
            if (oldTag != null)
                oldTags.Add(oldTag);
        }

        // Redundant?
        if (oldTags.Count == 0)
            return;

        // Simple rename?
        if (oldTags.Count == 1 && newTag == null)
        {
            oldTags[0].name = new_tag;
            oldTags[0].Save();
            scope.Complete();
            return;
        }

        // Create new tag?
        if (newTag == null)
        {
            newTag = new tag();
            newTag.name = new_tag;
            newTag.Save();
        }

        // Build a comma separated list of old tag id's for use in sql 'IN' clause
        var sql_old_tags = string.Join(",", (from t in oldTags select t.tag_id.ToString()).ToArray());

        // Step 1 - Retag, allowing duplicates for now
        var sql = @"
            UPDATE item_tags
                SET tag_id=@newtagid
                WHERE tag_id IN (" + sql_old_tags + @");
            ";

        // Step 2 - Delete the duplicates
        sql += @"
            DELETE t1 
                FROM item_tags t1, item_tags t2
                WHERE t1.tag_id=t2.tag_id 
                    AND t1.item_id=t2.item_id
                    AND t1.item_tag_id > t2.item_tag_id;
            ";

        // Step 3 - Update the use count of the destination tag
        sql += @"
            UPDATE tags 
                SET tags.count=
                    (
                        SELECT COUNT(items.item_id)
                        FROM items
                        INNER JOIN item_tags ON item_tags.item_id = items.item_id
                        WHERE items.published=1 AND item_tags.tag_id=@newtagid
                    )
                WHERE
                    tag_id=@newtagid;
            ";

        // Step 4 - Zero the use counts of the old tags and alias the old tag to the new tag
        sql += @"
            UPDATE tags
                SET tags.count=0,
                    alias=@newtagid
                WHERE tag_id IN (" + sql_old_tags + @");
            ";

        // Do it!
        megDB.CodingHorror(sql, newTag.tag_id, newTag.tag_id, newTag.tag_id, newTag.tag_id).Execute();
        scope.Complete();
    }
```

Comment: well your first and primary mistake is that you're not doing it server side - i didnt analyse your code further than that so can't comment anymore.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  There's a few bits up front that are done in code - but they're minor (get the id's of a couple of tags).  The bulk of the work is just 4 sql statements - they're not in loop or anything.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you correctly then you could try something like this:

```
/* new tag/item table clustered PK optimised for group by tag_id 
  or tag_id = ? queries !! */

drop table if exists tag_item;
create table tag_item
(
tag_id smallint unsigned not null,
item_id int unsigned not null,
primary key (tag_id, item_id), -- clustered PK innodb only
key (item_id)
)
engine=innodb;

-- populate new table with distinct tag/items

insert ignore into tag_item 
 select tag_id, item_id from item_tag order by tag_id, item_id;

-- update counters

update tag inner join
(
select 
 tag_id,
 count(*) as counter
from
 tag_item
group by
 tag_id
) c on tag.tag_id = c.tag_id
set
 tag.counter = c.counter;
```

Comment: Interesting - would this be faster than a simply updating the tag with a select count(*)? (assuming appropriate indicies present).

Comment: my understanding was...due to lack of entity integrity, namely a PK on item_tag table, that he had duplicate data (1,2),(1,3),(1,2) <-- oops and also required a re-mapping of some tags (which i omitted from my example as i'm lazy) so a re-count simply won't cut it. If you're worried about my choice of clustered PK for tag_item you might want to look at my response here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534597/rewriting-mysql-select-to-reduce-time-and-writing-tmp-to-disk/3535735#3535735

Answer (score 0):

An index/constraint on the `item_tag` table can prevent duplicate tags; or create the table with a composite primary key using both `item_id` and `tag_id`.

As to the counts, drop the `count` column from the `tag` table and create a VIEW to get the results:

`CREATE VIEW tag_counts AS SELECT tag_id, name, COUNT(*) AS count GROUP BY tag_id, name`

Then your count is always up to date.

Comment: I'd considered this for maintaining the counts but how would this perform on a large set of items?   Given that batch retagging is rare, and retrieving the counts frequent, a denormalized count column is I think justified.

Comment: If you are going to have millions of tags with infrequent update and frequent read, then yes, calculating the count each time is not the best solution. I just thought I'd mention it.
An alternative might be a materialized view, but I'm not sure that will help you since you still have to refresh them. (I also don't know if MySQL supports them, I mainly use SQL Server) :)